# How to view my website on another device

Tags: wordpress

I am using a local host on my laptop and creating a website on WordPress.How can I access my test site from another device.What are the possible ways of accessing the website.

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know, on which device you want to see your site? if you want to see your site on your mobile device by using your localhost then you have to connect your mobile to your pc & inspect it through chrome inspect device option.

For your reference: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

OR

You can deploy your site on any test server.